# How did Rapunzel know her birthday?

Tags: plot-explanation, tangled

Knowing that Rapunzel was taken by the witch in her early childhood, did her stepmother tell her the exact date she was born?

Comment: Question currently also exists on [Sci-Fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39747/how-did-rapunzel-know-her-birthday-in-the-movie-tangled).

Comment: Meh, exact cross-post. But I forgot the policy on those.

Comment: It's more suited here, so kill the one from scifi :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rapunzel was kidnapped by Mother Gothel when she was just a newborn, and she never met another person until Eugene came along. She mentioned her real birthday before that scene. So its clear that Mother Gothel told her the actual date of her birthday.

Comment: Oh, I see, do you think it would be better just to "lure" rapunzel about her real birth date?

Comment: It must be over confidence of gothel  to told her real Birth-date.